# Processing elseif command in php

Tags: php

I am trying to produce a particular treatment algorithm based on several clinical factors. On choosing the factors from a drop-down list menu in a form, the treatment algorithm will be proposed. While using elseif php commands, I am getting a syntax error. Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
        if(($t == '2' && ($n =='1') && ($er=='positive') && ($her == 'negative') && ($ki == 'Low (<14%)') && ($g=='G1') && ($ps == 'premenopause')) || (($t == '3' && ($n =='0') && ($er=='positive') && ($her == 'negative') && ($ki == 'Low (<14%)') && ($g=='G1') && ($ps == 'premenopause')) {  
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
        echo "T$t";
        echo "N$n";
        echo "M0.   ";
        echo "IIВ stage";
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Patient status: $ps";
        echo '<br />';
        echo "ER/PR status: $er" ;
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Her2/neu status: $her" ;  
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Ki-67 expression: $ki";
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Grade of differentiation: $g";
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Molecular subtype: Luminal А";
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<img src="/img/Tx.png" border=0>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';
        echo "$LumA3_1"; }
        else
        {
        echo "That combination does not exist";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: well, what is the error?

Comment: What's the error, where's the error?

Comment: Ever thought about different code formatting to make it more readable? This is extremely helpful in finding syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

In your if you have missed a ")" at the end.

```
) || ($t == '3' &&
//   ^ you start it here
```

so you need to change:

```
 ($ps == 'premenopause')) {
```

to

```
 ($ps == 'premenopause'))) {
//                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this you missed closing bracket  on first line in if statement

```
if($t == '2' && ($n =='1') && ($er=='positive') && ($her == 'negative') && ($ki == 'Low (<14%)') && ($g=='G1') && ($ps == 'premenopause') || ($t == '3' && ($n =='0') && ($er=='positive') && ($her == 'negative') && ($ki == 'Low (<14%)') && ($g=='G1') && ($ps == 'premenopause'))) { 
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo "T$t";
                echo "N$n";
                echo "M0.   ";
                echo "IIВ stage";
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Patient status: $ps";
                echo '<br />';
                echo "ER/PR status: $er" ;
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Her2/neu status: $her" ;  
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Ki-67 expression: $ki";
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Grade of differentiation: $g";
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Molecular subtype: Luminal А";
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<img src="/img/Tx.png" border=0>';
                echo '<br />';
                echo '<br />';
                echo "$LumA3_1"; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo "That combination does not exist";
            }
```

Comment: He is already closing it `echo "$LumA3_1"; }`

Comment: not at the end @Mr.Alien on the first line

Comment: Aaah nice catch but he will need 2 brackets I guess

Comment: Not sure what his exact if else condition is, but as per the naswer found sybtax error hence corrected and posted :0

Comment: Thank you so much all.. Problems solved now..

Comment: Cool @user2369942 cheers Just tick the answer so that it can be marked resolved if this or any other answer has helped you to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Close if bracket nearly premenopausa ")".Before first echo.